# How to stack variables together in cvxpy?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy

I want to solve an optimisation problem using `cvxpy`.
Suppose I want to use `log_sum_exp` function to build a constraint like this:

```
m >= log(1 + exp(m+z))
```

The syntax of `cvxpy` allows me to create a vector variable `x = [z,m]` of dimension `2` and apply matrix multiplication to create a vector of expressions `0, z+m`:

```
import cvxpy
x = cvxpy.Variable(2)
coeff = np.array([
    [0,0],
    [1,1]
])
constraints = [ x[1] >= cvxpy.log_sum_exp(coeff * x)]
```

When coding like this, I lose some part of the logic because I want different names for different parts of my variable array. Is there some way to use the `log_sum_exp` transform more explicitly, like

```
z = cvxpy.Variable()
m = cvxpy.Variable()
constraints = [ m >= cvxpy.log_sum_exp([0, m+z]) ]
```

?

I couldn't find any hints in the official docs. Thanks!

Comment: [vstack?](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/tutorial/functions/#vector-matrix-functions)

Comment: @sascha True, this can be achieved by typing `cvxpy.log_sum_exp(cvxpy.vstack(0, m+z))`. Should I write a separate answer for this?

Comment: I couldn't notice this part of manual and googling always threw me to the title page. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Feel free to add an answer connected to your code! That function-overview is my  goto-page when using cvxpy :-).

Comment: After two years, I was searching for the same question again and surprisingly, found my own post, it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [sascha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2320035/sascha) pointed out, one of the manual pages

[Functions in CVXPY](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/tutorial/functions/#vector-matrix-functions)

contains the answer. In particular, I can give an example of using `log_sum_exp` without matrix multiplication. Note that it is not possible to construct a correct problem within DCP (disciplined convex programming) framework using only operators `exp` and `log` because you will obtain concave function applied to convex one, which is considered as undefined behaviour. One should use a built-in constructor instead.

If you want to encode the constraint

```
F0 >= log( exp(F1) + exp(F2) + ... + exp(Fn) )
```

where `F1`, `F2`, ..., `Fn` are some convex expressions, and `F0` is a concave expression,
then instead of introducing slack variables, one can type

```
import cvxpy

... # Define variables and functions

constraints = [
    ...,
    something >= cvxpy.log_sum_exp(
        cvxpy.vstack(
            F1,
            F2,
            ...,
            Fn
        )
    )
]

... # Solve the optimisation problem
```

Note that `vstack` can be used both in multiple-argument style:

```
cvxpy.vstack(z, u)
```

and in list-style (but not tuples)

```
cvxpy.vstack([z,u])
```